# .finally is not a function when using async redux actions with promises

Tags: javascript, redux, bluebird

I'm writing a redux application using thunk middleware and experienced an issue regarding promises inside the async actions.

`db.getLoggedInUser()` returns a promise (Bluebird) that is fulfilled with a user object or a null (corresponding to the current logged in user).
If the user is logged in, I would like for fetch some relevant data, where `userActions.fetchUserInfo` is another async action (like initializeApp).

In the beginning of the process I'm dispatching a 'start_loading' action and after the all process is done - I'm dispatching a 'stop_loading' action.

```
export const initializeApp = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch(loadingActions.startLoading());

  return db.getLoggedInUser()
    .then((user) => {
      if (user) {
        return dispatch(userActions.fetchUserInfo(user.id));
      }
    })
    .catch(dbError => dispatch(errorActions.reportError(dbError.message)))
    .finally(() => dispatch(loadingActions.stopLoading()));
};
```

When dispatching initializeApp() I'm getting the following error:

> db.getLoggedInUser(...).then(...).catch(...).finally is not a function

**I'm getting this error regardless the resolved value of getLoggedInUser().**

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: `.finally` is a (non-standard) bluebird concept of Promises - ther's no indication in your code that you are actually using bluebird promises except for the [[tag]] and the fact that you are trying to use this non Promise/A+ method

Comment: All evidence suggests that `db.getLoggedInUser()` is *not* returning a Bluebird promise. Can you please show us its implementation?

Comment: You are both correct. This is my mistake. although db.getLoggedInUser() is my function (no an external API) I've returned an es6 Promise and NOT a Bluebird. Sorry, my bad.

Comment: [.finally](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally) is in the spec now